# How (if possible) can I determine the intersection between a line, and a function (whose input arguments are free variables)?

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a function `f(x,z)` that returns a height `y` in a terrain. I want to be able to determine where a line `P` intersects with the terrain.

A point `P=[px,py,pz]` along the line is defined as such:
`P = O + D*t`, where `O` is the origin of the line, `D` is the direction and `t` is some distance travelled from the origin.

Is it possible to compute the intersection between the line and the terrain with this information? If yes, then how?

Comment: If you tell us more about what the function $f$ looks like and the domain of input values we might be able to help. As the question is stated now it's too general. And I suspect linear algebra is the wrong tag, unless $f$ is linear.

Comment: I modified the tag to "numerical methods" instead, I think (and hope) it is more appropriate. The function `f` is not linear, and it is (in a sense) "unknown".

Comment: In what sense "unknown". Do you have a formula (no matter how complicated)? A class of possible formulas? Just a table of values on a grid? A small numerical example would be best. Without that kind of information I doubt you'll get much help.

Comment: The function retrieves height information about a terrain, and returns an interpolated value between the two nearest height samples. It's a function written in a computer program. By "unknown" I mean I don't really know how to explain it mathematically, and I guess it can't be really be analysed to help out here. I guess this means I would have to apply some kind of search algorithm to find the intersection point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I know enough now about the problem to venture a possible answer.

Step along the line at intervals $\Delta t$.  At each point, check that the pair $(x,z)$ is in the terrain, then calculate whether the height at that point is less than or equal to $f(x,z)$.

You'd have to experiment to find the right granularity $\Delta t$.

You might be able to speed things up if you had good bounds in advance for deciding when $(x,z)$ was in the domain or a maximum possible value for $y$ that would mean you didn't have to calculate $f$.

Note: I've followed your notation, but it's a little odd. I'd expect $(x,y)$ to specify a point in the domain and $z$ the height above that point.

Comment: Thanks. For now I'm using a binary search to find (approximately) a value for `t` where the line goes through the terrain. But I was thinking maybe there was some (feasible) way to find the exact value of `t`. Maybe there isn't, and your answer is as good as it gets.